# Media thumbnail for custom post inside post content

Tags: post-thumbnails, thumbnails

Some media are added to the post but not inserted into post content. How to insert media into post content without doing it manually. I was able to find the following code to display the attached thumbnail post inside the article content.

```
add_filter('the_content', 'put_thumbnail_in_posting');
function put_thumbnail_in_posting($content) {
    global $post;

    if ( has_post_thumbnail() && ( $post->post_type == 'post' ) ) {
        the_post_thumbnail( '', array( 'style' => 'float:left;margin:15px;' ) ); 
    }

    return $content;
}
```

Above function is tested and working. My question is how to adjust code to look for custom post type `advert` and insert the attached media to post content?

And how to make the function bring all the attached media not just one?

I already tested using `advert` in `post-type` `advert` and didn't work.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*@Ibraheem*, you don't have to use `global $post`, since it is in global. To check post type you can use [`get_post_type()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_post_type/).
Using `the_post_thumbnail` is not properly implemented in this case, instead use [`get_the_post_thumbnail`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_the_post_thumbnail/). Note: you can't use `has_post_thumbnail` as tag condition if you are not set featured image.

```
add_filter( 'the_content', 'put_thumbnail_in_posting' );
function put_thumbnail_in_posting( $content )
{
    if ( 'advert' == get_post_type() && has_post_thumbnail() )
    {
        $thumbnail = get_the_post_thumbnail( null, $size = '', array(
                'style' => 'float:left;margin:15px;'
        ) );

        $content = $thumbnail . $content; //thumbnail in top text
        /* $content = $content . $thumbnail; //thumbnail in bottom text  */
    }

    return $content;
}
```

To get all attachment in post, you can implement with the following way:

```
add_filter( 'the_content', 'put_thumbnail_in_posting' );
function put_thumbnail_in_posting( $content )
{
    if ( 'advert' == get_post_type() )
    {
        $args = array(
            'order'          => 'ASC',
            'post_mime_type' => 'image',
            'post_parent'    => get_the_ID(),
            'post_status'    => null,
            'post_type'      => 'attachment',
        );

        $attachments = get_children( $args );

        if ( $attachments ) {
            $thumbnails = '';
            foreach( $attachments as $attachment )
            {
                $thumbnails .= wp_get_attachment_image( $attachment->ID, $size = null, $icon = true, array(
                    'style' => 'float:left;margin:15px;'
                ) );
            }
            $content = $thumbnails . $content;
        }
    }
    return $content;
}
```

You can add another tag condition such as `is_home`, `is_single`, etc. and tweak thumb arguments in code that suit with your need.

Comment: Jevuska, thank you! just tested the code and it is working.

Comment: I used this and was sure it was working fine, however when going into the single view, the feature image is showing up in the html head too! So at the top of the page we get  the image twice above the header.

Comment: I have this problem too. It's related to Yoast SEO plugin.

Comment: I'm an idiot, I replied to myself.